# Question on a proof of $\zeta(3)\notin\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: irrational-numbers, riemann-zeta, modular-forms, modular-function

I have a question on [this article](http://wain.mi.ras.ru/zw/Beukers-Asterisque1987.pdf) proving $\zeta(3)\notin\mathbb{Q}.$ by using modular forms. This is theorem 1 at page 275 (page 5 in the pdf). Most things in the proof are clear but I don't get the penultimate sentence at all, e.g.

> Furthermore, it [$E(t)(f(t)-\zeta(3))$] cannot be a polynomial in $t$, since then $f(\tau)-\zeta(3)$ would be a modular form of weight $-2$, which is impossible.

I would say that this has something to do with $E(\tau)$ being modular of weight $2$ but I am really not sure.

Hoping that somebody out there has an idea for me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the argument is something like this.
Note that $t=t(\tau)$ is a meromorphic modular function for $\Gamma_1(6)$. Therefore,
if $E(t)(f(t)−\zeta(3))$ is a polynomial in $t$, then $E(\tau)(f(\tau)-\zeta(3))$ would be a meromorphic modular function for $\Gamma_1(6)$.
As you said, $E(\tau)$ is a modular form of weight $2$ for $\Gamma_1(6)$. It follows that $f(\tau)-\zeta(3)$ is a weight $-2$ modular form for $\Gamma_1(6)$. Such a form is necessarily $0$. Contradiction since the $3$rd derivative $(2\pi i)^3F$ of $f$ is nonzero.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is really nice. All makes sense but there are three questions left: #1: Why is $E(\tau)(f(\tau)-\zeta(3))$ a meromorphic modular function? #2: Why is $f(\tau)-\zeta(3)$ a modular form and not a meromorphic modular form? #3: Where du we (or the proof) use the identity $E\left(-\frac{1}{6z}\right)\left(f\left(-\frac{1}{6z}\right)-\zeta(3)\right)=E(z)(f(z)-\zeta(3))$?

Comment: #1: $E(\tau)(f(\tau)-\zeta(3))$ really means $E(t(\tau))(f(t(\tau))-\zeta(t(\tau)))$, and is therefore a meromorphic modular for $\Gamma_1(6)$ since $t(\tau)$ is so.

Comment: #2: As a triple primitive of the holomorphic function $(2\pi i)^3F$, $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbf H$ and at the cusps.

Comment: #3: This identity implies that $E(t)(f(t)-\zeta(3))$ has no branch point at $t=(\sqrt2-1)^4$, so that its radius of convergence is bigger than expected and that proposition 1.1 of the paper applies.

Comment: To #1: What has this to do with $E(t)(f(t)-\zeta(3))$ being a polynomial?